# GDAL and OGR Virtual Format, reading *.csv file and creating shapefile of lines

Tags: csv, shapefile, gdal

I have a text file (*.csv) and have successfully defined XYZ within that file to write a shapefile of points:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" testing.shp conduitout.vrt
```

My *.vrt file looks like this:

```xml
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="conduitout">
        <SrcDataSource>conduitout.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>EPSG:2232</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="start1" y="start2" z="start3"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

How do I change this so that I can write a shapefile of lines?  I have X1,Y1,Z1, and X2,Y2,Z2 in my input file (*.csv).  I imagine I do this by defining the the following in my *.vrt file:

```xml
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="conduitout">
        <SrcDataSource>conduitout.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbMultiLineString</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>EPSG:2232</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="WKB" />
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

But am not sure how to define the start and end points of each line from the columns of the *.csv file.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Wkb and Wkt, your geometry should be in a single column containing a valid Wkb or Wkt format. In the example below I use a WKT encoding because its a bit more readable. Also note that the Wkt geometries use commas, so your file can't have commas as a separator.

The 'csv' file:

```csv
Name;Lines
"Line1";LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30, 40 40)
"Line2";LINESTRING (5 10, 0 30, -30 40)
```

And the vrt file:

```xml
<OGRVRTDataSource>
       <OGRVRTLayer name="Linestest">
        <SrcDataSource SEPARATOR="SEMICOLON">D:\indata.csv</SrcDataSource> 
        <SrcLayer>indata</SrcLayer> 
        <GeometryType>wkbLineString</GeometryType> 
        <GeometryField encoding="WKT" field="Lines"/>
      </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

See Wikipedia for some more information on Wkt and Wkb formatting of geometries:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text

Answer (score 0):

Use "`LINESTRING()" instead of LINESTRING()`

Applied to previous example:

The 'csv' file:

```
Name;Lines
"Line1";"LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30, 40 40)"
"Line2";"LINESTRING (5 10, 0 30, -30 40)"
```